# How to unzip a zip file and copy the files into different different folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I want to unzip a zip file and want to copy the individual files in different different folders.

Let's for an example, I have a zip file with the name "Feeds.zip". In that I have 3 files name A,B,C. I want to copy these 3 files in different folders A1,B1,C1 respectively.

I have written the below code to unzip the file and know how to extract all the files. But as mentioned my requirement is a bit different.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Feeds.zip', "r") as z:
    z.extractall("C:/Desktop/")
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `extractall`, use `namelist` to get the names of all the members, then iterate over them and use `extract(member, path)` to extract them to whatever path you want.

In your example: (where the folders are **literally** `A1`,`B1`,`C1`)

```py
import os.path
with zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Feeds.zip', "r") as z:
    for member in z.namelist():
        dirname = os.path.basename(member) + "1"
        z.extract(member, dirname)
```

If the files have extensions and you dont want them to appear in the folder names, use `dirname = os.path.basename(member).split('.')[0] + "1"`.

Of course you can replace dirname with any other folder/path you want for each file. For instance, if you already have an array of paths to which you want to save the files, you can do

```py
for member,path in zip(z.namelist(), paths):
        z.extract(member, path)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer worked please consider [accepting it and voting it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).